# auto instance type changer for amazon ec2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling

Basically, I'd like to take large and x-large instances on EC2 and have them scale down to smalls during the late hours and on weekends automatically.  A few minute downtime wi.  I think this would cut my bills by 50%.  Does such a tool like this exist?

Comment: You will need to have an ELB and some kind of fancy autoscaling policy that starts instances the size you need. You can't change instance sizes, exactly, but you can shut down instances and start up others that do the same job. Not 100% sure you can do exactly what you want. Could you scale horizontally with many small instances instead of using difference instance sizes? What is your application doing?

Answer (score 0):

There are tools that can change the instance type of your EC2 instance on your schedule. Doing this effectively can save you quite a bit of money.

Some self-managed possibilities include:

- Scheduled Lambda functions
- Crontab scripts running on a server you manage

If you are looking for a third-party service, then you could look at Skeddly to do this for you.

Disclosure: I work for the company that is responsible for Skeddly.